# Is there a way to blame someone else or be able to change the blamee in subversion/TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn, local, blame

I have a project I am working on that is being version controlled on a local machine. I have changes made by another person outside of the network/company that I need to incorporate into my project but I want to be able to put the "blame" on them for the changes they make. I manually make the changes or I may just incorporate the changes they make by adding files and such. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: ...i am using the TortoiseBlame tool provided

Comment: @glowcoder got my upvote, if you saved your authorization in Tortoise then go into the options and Saved Data where you can clear your stored account and then use the one for them specifically as I assume you're doing this from your own machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a new subversion account for changes by them, and only commit their changes with that user.

Comment: yeah, you should only have a user commit their own changes, I suppose